# The common explanation to what happens before the Big Bang is wrong?

Tags: big-bang

When you ask a physicist what happens before the big bang, they will say - the question does not make sense cause there was no time, hence no "before" etc. And that Time appeared with the big bang. Ok...but isn't this a MASSIVE MASSIVE logical failure?

Because isn't Time appearing also a process in Time?

I can clarify a bit more. If we had two states - one without Time and the other with Time, how could we transition from the first state to the second state without Time? How can "change" happen (such as the appearance of Time with the Big Bang) if there was no Time initially?

Comment: I'm not a cosmologist but I don't think there is an agreed upon answer about what "before" the big bang means.

Answer (score 3):

General relativity is simply the theory that spacetime has a measurable shape and, in the presence of energy, that shape is not flat.

There is no particular logical reason to suppose, in advance, that the shape of the universe must be flat. So if it can be curved then we can measure its curvature and describe the shape mathematically.

In the case of the Big Bang cosmology, the shape of the universe is like a 4D trumpet. It has a pointy end, it gets wider and wider, and its cross section is uniform.

> isn't this a MASSIVE MASSIVE logical failure?

No. The shape of a trumpet is not a logical failure. It may not represent the actual shape of the universe, particularly at the pointy end, but that shape itself is not a logical failure. It is simply a shape.

> If we had two states - one without Time and the other with Time, how could we transition from the first state to the second state without Time?

Indeed, that would be illogical, and that is not claimed in GR. In GR every state has time. One of the defining features of the admissible shapes in GR is that at each point in the shape you can make an open neighborhood that is diffeomorphic to an open set of R4, and thus locally time can be defined at every point in the spacetime shape.

Nevertheless, that does not prevent shapes with pointy places, usually called singularities. It is a logical error to assume that a pointy shape implies a state without time. All states are in the universe and time is at each point in the universe’s shape.

Answer (score -2):

Welcome to the stack exchange. I'll give you two ideas to think about.

The first idea is that instead of a big bang there was a big crunch. Essentially this says that there was another universe before ours, and this universe contracted down to a singularity, or a very small point, and then expanded out again to our current universe. In this case then there certainly would have been time before what we consider the big crunch.

The second idea is more in line with big bang thinking. You have to understand that without space there is no time. This is the concept of space-time. Without a universe there is no time. Without space there is no time. This is a difficult concept to understand but once you get used to the concept of space-time, it becomes easier.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the concept of space-time. Of course. However, how can spacetime appear at some point if there was no spacetime before? Because "appearance" itself is Change, and Change can not happen without Time. So it boils down to either concept of Change being an illusion of lower dimensions or something else.

Comment: I'll be honest that you could spend a lifetime attempting to understand this, and you would still be counting the number of fairies on the head of a pin. Nobody really understands what happened before the big Bang, or the big crunch if that's what it was. And nobody even knows which one of those is correct or if either are correct. Good luck with this